# What is the most efficient way to trigger x actions per minute interval?

Tags: php, timer, intervals

Imagine a call center that cannot be inundated with customers by more than 2 calls per minute. So, anyone outside that range, would get an email support link ($bTrigger = FALSE). Everyone else ($bTrigger = TRUE) would get a tech support phone number.

The script is PHP. So, what's the most efficient and accurate way to build this?

This is what I have so far, but unfortunately it's only triggering once per minute. I can't seem to figure out why it won't run twice per minute.

```
<?php

$bTrigger = FALSE;
$sDir = dirname(__FILE__);
$sDir = rtrim($sDir,'/');
$sFile = $sDir . '/MINUTE-TIMER.txt';

$sLine = @ file_get_contents($sFile);
$sLine = str_replace("\r\n",'',$sLine);
$sLine = str_replace("\r",'',$sLine);
$sLine = str_replace("\n",'',$sLine);
$sLine = str_replace("\t",'',$sLine);
$asParts = explode(',',$sLine);
$nLetThru = @ $asParts[0];
$nLetThru = intval($nLetThru);
$nLastMin = @ $asParts[1];
$nLastMin = intval($nLastMin);
$nCurMin = intval(date('i'));
if (empty($sLine)) {
  $nLetThru = 0;
  $nLastMin = 0;
}

$nMaxLetThru = 2;

if ($nCurMin != $nLastMin) { // meaning, a new minute since last checked
  if ($nLetThru <= $nMaxLetThru) { // meaning, we haven't hit more than max allowed
    $bTrigger = TRUE;
    ++$nLetThru;
    file_put_contents($sFile,"$nLetThru,$nCurMin");
  } else {
    file_put_contents($sFile,"0,$nCurMin");
  }
}

if ($bTrigger) {
  echo 'TRIGGERED!!!!';
} else {
  echo 'not triggered';
}
```

Comment: We're here to help with specific problems, not do your job for you.

Comment: @MarcB I'm about to answer it, and then people can challenge that answer. I will learn from the challenges.

Comment: Your question needs improvement. If you have an answer, why not include it?

Comment: @njk Working as hard as I can on this. My algo that I'm running currently only triggers once per minute, when I need it to trigger twice per minute. So, I'm stuck and I'll keep trying. I'll paste what I have thus far.

Comment: Okay, enough with the downvotes and the close requests already. Where does it say in META that I can't show an example of code where I'm stuck and see if people can't fix it?

Comment: Huh?  "Not a real question?"  That's ridiculous!  Of course it's a real question.

The problem was a simple coding error: $nLetThru wasn't being reset when the minute changed.

Comment: @DaveBurton: Whilst your edit has the best intentions, it would be wrong to accept it. You can direct the OP to http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1120614 though, which contains the solution you proposed.

Comment: @Matt: no problem; since the question has been un-closed, I just posted the answer as an answer, which is obviously the better place for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a simple coding error: $nLetThru wasn't being reset when the minute changed. (Also, your <= should have been <, but you already noticed that.)

Here's the fixed code (based on the original version, in the question):

```
if (empty($sLine)) {
  $nLastMin = -1; # (instead of 0) just affects the 1st time thru, 1 chance in 60
}
```

...

```
if ($nCurMin != $nLastMin) { // new minute
  $bTrigger = TRUE;
  $nLetThru = 1;
} else { // another hit, same minute
  if ($nLetThru < $nMaxLetThru) { // not too many yet
    $bTrigger = TRUE;
    ++$nLetThru;
  }
}
if ($bTrigger) {
  file_put_contents($sFile,"$nLetThru,$nCurMin");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$bTrigger = TRUE;
$config = (object) array();
$config->THROTTLE_ENABLED = TRUE;
$config->THROTTLE_MAX_PER_MINUTE = 2;
if ($config->THROTTLE_ENABLED) {

    $bThrottleTrigger = FALSE;
    $sDir = dirname(__FILE__);
    $sDir = rtrim($sDir,'/');
    $sFile = $sDir . '/MINUTE-TIMER.txt';

    $sLine = @ file_get_contents($sFile);
    $sLine = str_replace("\r\n",'',$sLine);
    $sLine = str_replace("\r",'',$sLine);
    $sLine = str_replace("\n",'',$sLine);
    $sLine = str_replace("\t",'',$sLine);
    $asParts = explode(',',$sLine);
    $nLetThru = @ $asParts[0];
    $nLetThru = intval($nLetThru);
    $nLastMin = @ $asParts[1];
    $nLastMin = intval($nLastMin);
    $nCurMin = intval(date('i'));
    if (empty($sLine)) {
        $nLetThru = 0;
        $nLastMin = 0;
    }

    if ($nCurMin != $nLastMin) { // meaning, a new minute since last checked
        if ($nLetThru < $config->THROTTLE_MAX_PER_MINUTE) { // meaning, we haven't hit more than max allowed
            $bThrottleTrigger = TRUE;
            ++$nLetThru;
            @ file_put_contents($sFile,"$nLetThru,$nLastMin");
        } else {
            @ file_put_contents($sFile,"0,$nCurMin");
        }
    } else {
        @ file_put_contents($sFile,"0,$nCurMin");
    }

    if (!$bThrottleTrigger) { // will be like most of the time
        $bTrigger = FALSE; // don't show the number
    }

} // end if ($config->THROTTLE_ENABLED)
```

Comment: That's almost right, but it's when the minute has NOT changed that you need to check the count.  When the minute HAS changed, you should go ahead and let the user through, and set the counter to 1.  When the minute has NOT change, then check the counter, and if it's less than 2 then increment it an let the call through, otherwise don't let the call through.